# Terminal not retaining preference changes

Tags: terminal, mobile-device-management

I've set a custom font on my default Terminal profile (normal terminal, not iTerm2 etc.) and every-time I restart my machine I need to reset the font.

The same behaviour also occurs if I reset the font following a boot, then quit the terminal, and re-open it.

To resolve things on a new boot, I need to go and rename/delete the following file: `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist` , and then re-launch Terminal.

Now if I set the font, and quit the application, the setting sticks!

Looking at ownership of this file w. `ls -l | grep Terminal` I can see that the original is owned by `root`, and the newly created one owned by my user/..

```
❯ ls -l | grep Terminal
-rw-------   1 root        wheel  18022  5 Dec 13:06 com.apple.Terminal.Old.plist
-rw-------   1 my.user     staff  18073  3 Jan 13:10 com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

So, it would seem that maybe my `com.apple.Terminal.plist` is getting re-created at boot by the system? When I reboot, this file cannot be opened either, which is strange, as if it is locked, blocked, corrupt for editing, which is why probably the font setting isn't retained in there until it is recreated.

Anyone have any thoughts on why this might be occurring at all? My device is managed by JAMF, but the sysadmins don't have any real insight in to why this might be occurring.

***Update:** It has happened again this morning, I have not shut down the machine but i did move it (unplug power and travel for 45mins), and the settings have re-set themselves.*

```
❯ ls -l | grep Terminal
-rw-------   1 root        wheel   17709  4 Jan 12:33 com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

i can easily resolve the problem with:

```
sudo chown my.user com.apple.Terminal.plist
```

but this is really really weird!

Comment: Did you double-check that Prefs > General > On Startup matches Prefs > Profiles > [Default] ? This catches me out every time.

Comment: i have checked that, and they do indeed match.. it has now happened again after i moved the machine at 12:33 yesterday, most strange!!